# Load pre-written objects instead of writing them all[Plugin system]

Tags: java, oop

Well im (trying) to make an object system where i can load in classes or .java files from a folder, probably called "plugins" and they will add to an arraylist called "base" and base will controll the objects and loop them, dont worry i have examples for everything.

But ill explain how it works first.

Theres a base class that these plugins will extend from (BaseHack), the arraylist all the objects extending BaseHack will be added to. i write my own classes and add them to the arraylist manuelly, but i was thinking if people could make there own classes and load them into the plugin directory instead of me manually doing it.

Code examples:
Something extending the object base:

```
package crow.ingame.hacks;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.List;

import net.minecraft.src.Entity;
import net.minecraft.src.EntityLiving;
import net.minecraft.src.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.src.MouseHelper;
import net.minecraft.src.Packet19EntityAction;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import crow.controller.BaseHack;
import crow.controller.BaseHackController;
import crow.main.Crow;

public class BunnyHop extends BaseHack{

    public float clickDelay = 0;
    public BunnyHop() 
    {
        super(true,false,false,"BunnyHop", "-hop", "Auto Hops for pvping", 0xFF75ffaf , Keyboard.KEY_J,Keyboard.KEY_J);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGameTick()
    {
        if(enabled)
        {
            if(Crow.mc.inGameHasFocus && Crow.mc.theWorld != null && !(BaseHackController.getBaseByCMD("-nofall").enabled))
            {
                Robot robot;
                try {
                    robot = new Robot();
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                } catch (AWTException e)     {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable()
    {
        Robot robot;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        } catch (AWTException e)     {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How i add the hacks:

```
public static void AddHacks()
{
    //Hacks
    Fly fly = new Fly();
    Sprint sprint = new Sprint();
    Aimbot aimbot = new Aimbot();
    KillAura killaura = new KillAura();
    AutoBlock autoblock = new AutoBlock();
    NoFall nofall = new NoFall();
    Freecam freecam = new Freecam();
    Xray xray = new Xray();
    Step step = new Step();
    FullBright fullbright = new FullBright();
    BunnyHop hop = new BunnyHop();
    base.add(hop);
    base.add(fullbright);
    base.add(step);
    base.add(xray);
    base.add(freecam);
    base.add(nofall);       
    base.add(autoblock);
    base.add(aimbot);
    base.add(sprint);
    base.add(killaura);
    base.add(fly);
    //CMD
    Friends friends = new Friends();
    CMDController cmdcontroller = new CMDController();
    crow.ingame.cmd.Settings settings = new crow.ingame.cmd.Settings();
    base.add(settings);
    base.add(cmdcontroller);
    base.add(friends);
}
```

Could someone show me how to load a class like my bunny hop then add it in to the arraylist?
Thanks!<3

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to create instances of various classes without hard-coding the class names into your source.  [This can be done via reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) as follows:

```
String className = "crow.ingame.hacks.BunnyHop";

try {
    Class myClass = Class.forName(className);
    BaseHack object = (BaseHack)myClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
    base.add(object);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //TODO - Proper Exception handling
}
```

This will work as long as the folder containing the `.class` files for the classes you are trying to load is in your Classpath; this will not work if just `.java` files are put in the folder.  In other words, make sure you add your `plunins` folder to the Classpath.

Comment: But when i try to make a class for loading(or someone else does)
It gives ma heaps of errors.(I.E. i copied a whole class and saved it as .java, then used cmd to compile it but it wont compile due to errors. how can i make classes that i can load in?

Comment: The short answer is that you have to make the `.java` compile to a `.class` using the `javac` command as the JVM doesn't understand anything else.  If you post another question about the compilation errors then that problem can be solved. My guess is that you're not setting the Classpath properly for the compile.

Comment: What do you mean setting the class path? i have only created very basic java applications outside minecraft java stuff. and thats all set up for me.

Comment: The Classpath tells `javac` where to find classes that your code depends on.  Classes like `java.util.List` are built-in but you need to tell Java where to find other classes like `net.minecraft.src.Entity`.  It's probably worth working through a Java tutorial to learn the basics. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167179/java-tutorial